# Who runs the Econ SE Twitter account and how can we reactivate it?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So I've been looking at the [Economics SE Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackEcon)  and am wondering who runs it and is it possible to  reactivate it? The pros of having a network Twitter account would be:

- Promotion of site and posts so posts get more views.
- attracting more users to participate and contribute content.

So how do we get this twitter account? should we make a new one?

**UPDATE: Economics SE Twitter  is live!**
https://twitter.com/EconomicsSE

Comment: It is nice to have an active and enthusiastic member of Econ SE like you. I am glad you made this work. I do not use Twitter myself, but I appreciate the idea.

Comment: [Why doesn't the Eco SE twitter account tweet bounties? Why hasn't it been active for a year?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/why-doesnt-the-eco-se-twitter-account-tweet-bounties-why-hasnt-it-been-active)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the official SE Twitter accounts were controlled by us. That particular one actually belonged to the [original Economics site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) which was closed in 2012 around the time of the last tweet from the account.

We [stopped creating Twitter accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548) for new sites some time ago - it's just not worthwhile to integrate them anymore given the low engagement and hassle of getting them unblocked with Twitter. It's unlikely we'd ever re-activate the existing one, as it'd probably end up getting blocked by Twitter if it started up again and that's exactly the kind of thing we don't want to deal with, <s>but I can bounce the idea off some people and see if it's in the cards, y'know, since it does already exist</s>.

So apparently [this has also come up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295011/could-we-have-the-ability-to-control-a-sites-twitter-feed-from-a-chat-room), and the simple answer is you should feel free to create and operate your own Twitter account, but we cannot hand over the existing one that we operated. If you *do* go on to create your own Twitter account for the site, let us know and we will deactivate the existing one to prevent any confusion. Please make sure you follow the advice in the linked post as well.

Comment: Oh, I'm just trying to figure out ways to promote the site. Cross validated has a rather well followed twitter (I may be baised because two of my posts were shared on  it) and I think the use of social media would help promote the site. Why haven't facebook pages/linkedin blogs  been made?

Comment: @EconJohn I think a blog on current economic topics(undergrad, grad and research) would be a great thing. John, I like to see your engagement with the community. Congrats!

Comment: @EconJohn Updated the answer with some more info for you.

Comment: @animuson so I should just make one? wow. Ok Econ.SE (unoffical?) Twitter is happening.

Comment: @animuson Its live! https://twitter.com/EconomicsSE

Comment: @EconJohn We've deactivated the old account for you to prevent confusion. Good luck!

Comment: [Why doesn't the Eco SE twitter account tweet bounties? Why hasn't it been active for a year?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/why-doesnt-the-eco-se-twitter-account-tweet-bounties-why-hasnt-it-been-active)

Comment: @BCLC That account is not controlled by SE. It is created and maintained by the community, so there is no information I could provide about why it went inactive.

Comment: @animuson thanks! who is/are 'the community' exactly please?

Comment: @BCLC Afaik EconJohn created the account. I'm not a contributor here so I have no clue what happened with the account after it was created here. All I know is it's not an official account and is not tied into any of our systems for auto-tweeting.

Comment: @animuson thanks!